# Accessing Update(GameTime) when implementing Monogame in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, monogame

So I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-JupOxwB-k on how to implement monogame within winforms. I've been successful by following the tutorial from scratch to finish. Sadly there is only one video in the tutorial series.

I've created a class that inherits from GraphicsDeviceControl in order to draw it on a windows form. Now, this works in the sense that I have implemented the control onto the form. But it only draws the thing once. I need to implement the GameTime in an Update(GameTime) somehow but I have no idea how as this entire crossover between winforms and monogame is difficult enough.

So many tutorials or posts have outdated links or are outdated and no longer applicable. I tried following this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/12/06/when-winforms-met-game-loop/

But I just feel so stupid I can't get it to work. What is Tick? What is TargetElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds? No code snippet on that page helps me.

TL;DR:
I want an Update(GameTime) and my Draw() to happen once per frame inside the xna control that I've added to the winform. How do I implement this behavior?

Comment: In winforms you have to implement that yourself by creating them and calling them at the appropriate time

Comment: You may also want to look into [this](http://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-forms-create-your-editor-environment/9954)